# How to preload bundle in asp.net mvc 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using following code, to add bundle to my layout.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ngapp")
```

I would also like to preload our Bundle, but I do not know exact name and query string version which will be rendered after deploy.
How can I change this piece of code to be something like this:

```
  <link rel="preload" href="@Scripts.BundleName("~/bundles/ngapp")" as="script">
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ngapp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are multiple ways to do this.

You can make use of the 'ResolveBundleUrl':

```
<link rel="preload" href="@(BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/scripts"))" as="script">
```

Or you can use the 'Scripts.RenderFormat':

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<link rel='preload' href='{0}' as='script'>", "~/bundles/scripts")
```